# Bringing together coalesce, count, case and clauses

Tags: sql, coalesce

I'm new to this so please bear with me.

I'm writing a query where I need to count the number of rows with two specific values,

I have used the following to get the result of the different values in one field but I need to know the results only if another field is set to a specific value.  I pulled the following from a previous question on this site:

```
COALESCE(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 2 THEN 1 end),0) as ALLJOBROLES_2,
coalesce(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 3 then 1 end), 0) as ALLJOBROLES_3,
coalesce(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 4 then 1 end), 0) as ALLJOBROLES_4,
coalesce(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 7 then 1 end), 0) as ALLJOBROLES_7,
coalesce(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 8 then 1 end), 0) as ALLJOBROLES_8,
coalesce(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 23 then 1 end), 0) as ALLJOBROLES_23,
coalesce(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 24 then 1 end), 0) as ALLJOBROLES_24,
coalesce(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 25 then 1 end), 0) as ALLJOBROLES_25'
```

As part of a larger query, I want to do the above only if `CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add the condition into the `where` clause:

```
COALESCE(count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 2 and CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 THEN 1 end),0) as ALLJOBROLES_2,
```

By the way, the `COALESCE()` should be unnecessary.  `COUNT()` will return `0` if there are no matches.

Comment: Thank you I'm sure I tried this but must had got my parenthesis incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to surround each expression with another CASE WHEN construct:

```
CASE WHEN CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 THEN
  count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 2 THEN 1 end)
ELSE
  NULL
END as ALLJOBROLES_2,
CASE WHEN CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 THEN
  count(case when CW.MAINJOBROLE = 3 THEN 1 end)
ELSE
  NULL
END as ALLJOBROLES_3,
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use SUM() and not COUNT().

```
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 2 THEN 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_2,
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 3 then 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_3,
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 4 then 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_4,
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 7 then 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_7,
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 8 then 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_8,
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 23 then 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_23,
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 24 then 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_24,
SUM(case when CW.EMPLSTATUS = 1 AND CW.MAINJOBROLE = 25 then 1 end) as ALLJOBROLES_25
```